# How to add additional files to an ad hoc Roslyn workspace to expose them to analyzers

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am creating some Roslyn analyzers, that use the `AdditionFiles` feature to access a settings file. I am trying to test the analyzers use this correctly.

I have a method that sets up an ad hoc test workspace, and I've tried adding additional documents via two routes:

```
private static Project CreateProject(IEnumerable<string> sources)
{
    var projectId = ProjectId.CreateNewId(TestProjectName);

    var solution = new AdhocWorkspace()
        .CurrentSolution
        .AddProject(projectId, TestProjectName, TestProjectName, LanguageNames.CSharp)
        .AddMetadataReference(projectId, CorlibReference)
        .AddMetadataReference(projectId, SystemCoreReference)
        .AddAdditionalDocument(DocumentInfo.Create(DocumentId.CreateNewId(projectId),
                                                    "arnolyzer.yaml",
                                                    filePath: @"..\..\arnolyzer.yaml"));

    var count = 0;
    foreach (var source in sources)
    {
        var newFileName = $"{DefaultFilePathPrefix}{count++}.{CSharpDefaultFileExt}";
        var documentId = DocumentId.CreateNewId(projectId, newFileName);
        solution = solution.AddDocument(documentId, newFileName, SourceText.From(source));
    }
    var settingsFileId = DocumentId.CreateNewId(projectId, "arnolyzer.yaml");
    solution = solution.AddAdditionalDocument(settingsFileId, "arnolyzer.yaml", SourceText.From(@"..\..\arnolyzer.yaml"));
    return solution.GetProject(projectId);
}
```

Examining the `Project` instance, I can see that both additional documents have been added.

However, when inspecting `CompilationStartAnalysisContext.Options.AdditionalFiles` within a `AnalysisContext.RegisterCompilationStartAction` action, `AdditionalFiles` is empty.

Does anyone know whether this approach should work and thus whetehr I've gone wrong somewhere? Or are the additional documents added to a `Project` unrelated to the `AditionalFiles` feature?

Comment: To answer your easy question: yes, AdditionalDocument is what matches the compiler AdditionalFiles feature. It looks like you're adding the file twice though? Also, I'm not sure we support relative paths in the file name, what if you change that to a full path?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski. I am adding the file twice as I was adding it via two means to test whether one worked and the other didn't. I tried the full path and it made no difference unfortunately. The method used by Tamas in his answer works for me though so I'll use that. Thanks.

Comment: You still may wish to file a bug on https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn though; either this shouldn't have failed, or at least requires some updated docs somewhere.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski, good idea Jason, I'll try and construct a minimal project that demonstrates the issue and will submit it as a bug. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4655

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will not directly answer your question, but you mention that you are trying to test analyzers if they use the additional file or not. So, here is how we solve that:

```
var compilationWithAnalyzer = compilation.WithAnalyzers(
  diagnosticAnalyzers,
  new AnalyzerOptions(ImmutableArray.Create<AdditionalText>(new AnalyzerAdditionalFile(configuration.Path))),
  tokenSource.Token);
var diagnostics = await compilationWithAnalyzer.GetAnalyzerDiagnosticsAsync();
```

where `AnalyzerAdditionalFile` just extends `AdditionalText`:

```
public sealed class AnalyzerAdditionalFile : AdditionalText
{
  private readonly string path;

  public AnalyzerAdditionalFile(string path)
  {
    this.path = path;
  }

  public override string Path => path;

  public override SourceText GetText(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    return SourceText.From(File.ReadAllText(path));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tamas, This approach works correctly for me. My problem is now solved. Odd the approach I was taking didn't work though.